# Entity Framework - CF/FA - Define filtered navigation properties in POCOs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship, fluent, navigation-properties

I am using Entity Framework with the Code first approach and the fluent API. Given the following POCO classes...

```cs
class A {
  public A {
    this.Cs = new HashSet<C>();
    this.Bs = new HashSet<B>();
  }

  public long Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B {
  public B {
    this.Cs = new HashSet<C>();
  }

  public long Id { get; set; }
  public virtual A A { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<C> Cs { get; set }
}

public class C {
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public virtual A A { get; set; }
  public virtual B B { get; set; }
}
```

... I want to define the following relationships with the Fluent API, but I do not know how or if this is even possible.

I want that the navigation property Cs of class A contains all objects of class C where c.A is set to this instance of A and c.B is null. I want that Bs of class A contains all objects of B where b.A is set to this instance of A. I want that the navigation property Cs of class B contains all objects of class C where C.a is set to B.a and C.b is set to this instance of B.

An example should illustrate this better:

```
+------+------+-----+
| C.Id | C.A  | C.B |
+------+------+-----+
| 1    | 1    |     |
| 2    | 1    |     |
| 3    | 1    | 1   |
| 4    | 1    | 2   |
+------+------+-----+
```

Then A.Cs contain { 1, 2 } and A.Bs contain { 1, 2 } where B[id=1].Cs contains { 3 } and B[id=2].Cs contains { 4 }.

Therefore I would just need the information for the navigation properties of the table that is created for the C objects. Is it possible to tell the Entity framework via the fluent API how it should work with those navigation properties?

What I've done now is that I told the EF to ignore the navigation properties and I've overwritten the get method, but this is not the perfect solution I am searching since I would love the POCOs to remain untouched in any way.

It would be great if someone could tell me if that is even possible and what the prefered solution/common practice for such constructs is.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use either Fluent or Data Annotations or just simple naming Conventions to define relationships between tables, but you can't use either to determine what data goes into the tables. You can set required fields, primary keys, foreign keys.  Relationships can be 1:1 or 1:0,1 or 1:many or many:many, etc. But there is no way to tell it that a particular ICollection contains ALL matching items.  That would be the responsibility of your business logic to ensure that when an item is added to table C it is also added to A's ICollection.